# ABCD is a line segment, AB = BC = CD. P is any point on circle with BC as diameter. If the angles ∠APB = α and ∠CPD = β. Prove that, $4\tanα\tanβ= 1$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $ABCD$ is a line segment, trisected by the points $B$ and $C$. $P$ is any point on the circle where $BC$ is its diameter. If the angles $\angle APB$ and $\angle CPD$ are respectively $\alpha$ and $\beta$, prove that $$4\tan\alpha ⋅ \tanβ = 1$$

[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried dropping perpendiculars from $B$ and $C$ to $AP$ and $DP$ to get $tan\alpha$ and $tan\beta$ in terms of sides but I don't know how to utilise that. I also can't think of any other way to get $\tan\alpha$ and $\tan\beta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since triangles $ABP$, $BCP$ and $CDP$ have common altitude from vertex $P$ and $AB = BC = CD$, these three triangles have same area:
$$
\frac{1}{2}|AP|\cdot|BP|\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2}|BP|\cdot|CP| = \frac{1}{2}|CP|\cdot|DP|\sin\beta
$$
which implies
$$
|BP| = |DP|\sin\beta, \quad |CP| = |AP|\sin\alpha.
$$

On the other hand, we have $S_{APD} = S_{ABP} + S_{BCP} + S_{CDP} = 3S_{BCP}$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}|AP|\cdot|DP|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha + \beta\right) = \frac{3}{2}|BP|\cdot|CP| = \frac{3}{2}|DP|\sin\beta\cdot|AP|\sin\alpha
$$
which gives us
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha + \beta\right) = 3\sin\alpha\sin\beta
$$
$$
\cos(\alpha + \beta) = 3\sin\alpha\sin\beta
$$
$$
\cos\alpha\cos\beta = 4\sin\alpha\sin\beta
$$
$$
4\tan\alpha\tan\beta = 1
$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

[image]

Extend $PB$ to $E$ such that $PB=BE$.

Similarly extend $PC$ to $F$ such that $PC=CF$.

Join the lines as shown.

$(1)$ Note that $AB=BC$ and $PB=BE$ $\implies PAEC$ is a parallelogram.

$(2)$ Hence $AP // EC$ and $\alpha=x$.

$(3)$ Note that $\angle BPC=90^{\text o}.$

$(4)$  $$\therefore \tan \alpha = \tan x= \frac{PC}{PE} 
  \tag{1}$$

$(5)$ Similarly $$\tan \beta = \tan y = \frac{PB}{PF} 
 \tag{2}$$

$(6)$ From (4) and (5),
$$\tan \alpha \times \tan \beta = \frac{PC \times PB}{PE \times PF}$$

$(7)$ $\because$ $PF= 2 \times PC$ and $PE = 2 \times PB$,

$(8)$ $$\therefore \tan \alpha \times \tan \beta = \frac{1}{4}$$